# Is there any cost to increase the AWS limit on the total number of cloudformation stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-billing

I believe the current limit for the total number of cloudformation stacks is 200 stacks. Does it cost anything to request an increase in this limit? I have started using cloudformation and I'm concerned I will reach this limit as the infrastructure scales (especially when using nested stacks).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer service-related question regarding costs or pricing and not a programming question. Contact Amazon Customer Service directly.

Answer (score 2):

There is no cost to increase any AWS limit.